# ggPlotting time series in R with intervals on x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, time-series

I am plotting time series in R using ggplot2. Instead of having points in time on the x-axis, I want to have intervals (e.g. years) on the axis. For example:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("xts")

my_data = as.xts(economics[,2:5],order.by=economics$date,frequency="monthly")
my_data_smpl=last(my_data,'10 years')
ppp <- ggplot(data=my_data_smpl) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=index(my_data_smpl),y=psavert))+
  xlab("")
print(ppp)
```

This code results in the following plots:

[image: plot_with_points_in_time]

What I would want is something like this (note the re-positioned axis labels):

[image: plot_with_time_intervals]

Can this be done automatically, ie. is there a generic/flexible solution which does not rely on manual repositioning of the labels? Similar issues arise when working with higher frequency date (e.g. daily data) and having months on the axis.

Thank you
Ferdinand

Comment: Not normally a great idea, but could you subtract 6 months from every date so the labels end up centered on the year?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are assuming that the grid lines will be precisely where they are and always 1 year wide. I don't think this is safe (if your data changes time-span, for instance), so I think you need to be explicit on gridlines in addition to solving your current dilemma. BTW: I do not interpret tick-less years in your desired plot obvious-enough to know precisely what you are conveying. It might be just me, but I suggest your desired plot is not fully intuitive.

Comment: @Jordo82, that's a good first suggestion, but I suggest the consequences of that are significant if any other layers are added (that rely on the x-axis values): you'd need to remember to always change the date of everything going into the plot, I'd think you are much more likely to forget one *and never know it*. I'd think controlling the labels and their placement would be much safer.

Comment: Ferdinand, any other solution (as I just commented to Jordo82) would be hackish and much more likely to cause problems in other unforeseen ways. Is there a reason you are averse to shifting the labels? It seems to me to be the cleanest/safest approach.

Comment: Dear both, thanks for taking an interest. Jordo82's idea works, but need more playing around with the layout (e.g. regarding the gridlines) to make the plot intuitive. Shifting the labels seems to make many of these adjustments necessary as well, and I fear things will not work reliably if the data changes (as rightfully pointed out by r2evans).

Comment: To clarify what I am looking for (and possibly as a starting point for the solution), have a look at the chart in this press release (which uses columns rather than lines as in my question, but that shouldn't play a role, I assume):

https://www.bea.gov/news/2018/gross-domestic-product-third-quarter-2018-second-estimate-corporate-profits-third-quarter

Would it be possible to have a second line of x-axis labels? If I just drop the first line of x-axis labels and leave the second line unchanged, I should end up where I want.

Comment: Perhaps related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759676/specification-of-first-and-last-tick-marks-with-scale-x-date (and specifically `ggplot2::scale_x_date`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect what you are actually looking is a way to use facets with free scales. Facet labels are naturally positioned in the middle of each plot panel:

```
# convert the xts object to data frame, & define date / year explicitly
data <- as.data.frame(my_data_smpl)
data$date <- index(my_data_smpl)
data$year <- format(data$date, "%Y")

p <- ggplot(data = data) +
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = psavert)) +
  facet_grid(~ year, scales = "free", switch = "x")
p
```

[image: plot with default theme]

You can also tweak the appearance to imitate the one you [linked](https://www.bea.gov/news/2018/gross-domestic-product-third-quarter-2018-second-estimate-corporate-profits-third-quarter):

```
p +
  scale_x_date(expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "pt"),
        strip.background = element_blank())
```

[image: with tweaked theme]