# How to define origin for date_breaks in scale_x_date

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the data and plot below. Defining `date_breaks` with every three months, the first break is `feb`. But I would like to start with `jan`. It works for every two months, see second plot. I tried to specify limits (see code) to no avail.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df_foo <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c('2008-06-01','2008-07-01','2008-07-01','2009-04-01','2009-04-01','2010-04-01')))

ggplot(df_foo, aes(x = date)) + 
  stat_count(geom = 'line', aes(y = ..count..)) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = '3 months', date_labels = '%b', 
               limits = c(as.Date('2008-01-01'), as.Date('2010-12-01')))
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(df_foo, aes(x = date)) + 
  stat_count(geom = 'line', aes(y = ..count..)) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = '2 months', date_labels = '%b', 
               limits = c(as.Date('2008-01-01'), as.Date('2010-12-01')))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-11-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Have you tried this: [Specification of first and last tick marks with scale_x_date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759676/specification-of-first-and-last-tick-marks-with-scale-x-date)

Comment: @Henrik This solution works. Thanks for pointing it out. Basically a dupe. (Happy for it to be marked as such :)  I wasn't aware that one could specify date intervals like that in `seq` too (in my case `seq(by = '3 months')` works!