# ggplot: date axis. How to set limits?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Look at this plot:

```
require(tidyverse)
require(lubridate)

(
  tibble(
    date = ymd("2019/12/31") + 1:366,
    value = rnorm(1:366))
  %>% ggplot(aes(date, value))
   +  geom_line()
   +  scale_x_date("Day", date_labels = "%b %d", date_breaks = "10 days")
   +  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
)
```

[image]

I want to set new origin x axis to start at Jan 1st and to end at Dec. 31st.

I have tried this:

```
(
  tibble(
    date = ymd("2019/12/31") + 1:366,
    value = rnorm(1:366))
  %>% ggplot(aes(date, value))
   +  geom_line()
   +  scale_x_date("Day", date_labels = "%b %d", date_breaks = "10 days"
                   , limits = ymd(c("2020/01/01", "2020/12/31")))
   +  expand_limits(x = ymd(c("2020/01/01", "2020/12/31")))
   +  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
)
```

But it does not work... (nothing changes)

Comment: possibly very related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759676/specification-of-first-and-last-tick-marks-with-scale-x-date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for. Via the limits you set the range of the data. However, you have to keep in mind that ggplot2 by default expands a continuous axis by 5 percent on each side. The amount of expansion can be set via the `expand` argument. Additionally, if you want a specific start and/or end age then I would suggest to set the breaks via the `breaks` arguement instead of using `date_breaks`:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

set.seed(42)
tibble(
  date = ymd("2019/12/31") + 1:366,
  value = rnorm(1:366)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date, value)) +
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_date("Day", breaks = seq(ymd("2020/01/01"), ymd("2020/12/31"), by = "10 days"), date_labels = "%b %d",
               limits = ymd(c("2020/01/01", "2020/12/31")),
               expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: lol, I was literally just in the same second going to post the same :)